Problem with connecting PHP files. One has the connection to DB and the other one is for a html form
I am having problem connecting php files. The form.php is just for data to be send to DB and the other one is just the connection to DB. The connection and the php code for the form cant be together in one code.
This is the structure:
project/
│
├── module/
│   └── form.php
└── system/
    └── access.php

I tried this:
require_once 'system/access.php';

Does not work.
I dont want to use current pc path like this:
C:\wamp64\www\Project\system\access.php

Does require_once '../system/access.php'; work?
